# 'January-2016' string date in SQL Server - increment by one month

Tags: sql-server, datetime

```
January-2016
August-2017
November-2018
January-2018
August-2018
November-2018
```

This is my date format how to increment month by 1 ?

Comment: If the value is a string based data type it by definition isn't a date. Dates also contain a year, month *and* **day**; your values don't have a day. You can easily add a month (or any time span) to a date and time value with `DATEADD`, but you first need a valid date (and time) value.

Comment: Why is that your date format? That seems like a poorly-chosen, language-specific string representation of a month. Have you considered storing a proper `date` instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(20) = 'January-2016'

SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH , 1 , 
                    DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(@Str, 4) ,  DATEPART (MONTH, REPLACE(@Str , '-' , ' 01 ')) , 1)
                    ) 
            , 'MMMM-yyyy')

Result: February-2016
```

Comment: Note that the Format function performs very poor

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the dash with `' 1 '`, as long as you explicitly use English:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english;

DECLARE @s varchar(67) = 'January-2016';  

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, REPLACE(@s, '-', ' 1 '));
```

So then add a month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, <try_convert expression>);
```